# Running sums from one column conditional on values in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a dataset containing data values associated with times (amongst other categories), and I'd like to add an accumulated value column - that is, the sum of all values up to and including the time. So, taking something like this:

```
   ID  YEAR  VALUE
0   A  2018    144
1   B  2018    147
2   C  2018    164
3   D  2018    167
4   A  2019    167
5   B  2019    109
6   C  2019    183
7   D  2019    121
8   A  2020    136
9   B  2020    187
10  C  2020    170
11  D  2020    188
```

and adding a column like this:

```
   ID  YEAR  VALUE  CUMULATIVE_VALUE
0   A  2018    144               144
1   B  2018    147               147
2   C  2018    164               164
3   D  2018    167               167
4   A  2019    167               311
5   B  2019    109               256
6   C  2019    183               347
7   D  2019    121               288
8   A  2020    136               447
9   B  2020    187               443
10  C  2020    170               517
11  D  2020    188               476
```

Where e.g. in row 7 the CUMULATIVE_VALUE is the sum of the 2 VALUE for ID="D" in years 2018 and 2019 (and **not** 2020).

I've looked at `cumsum()` but can't see how I could use it in this specific case so the best I've come up with is this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

ids=["A","B","C","D"]
years=[2018,2019,2020]

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": np.tile(ids, 3), 
                   "YEAR": np.repeat(years, 4), 
                   "VALUE": np.random.randint(100,200,12)})
print(df)

df["CUMULATIVE_VALUE"] = None 
for id in ids:
  for year in years:
    df.loc[(df.ID==id) & (df.YEAR==year), "CUMULATIVE_VALUE"] = \
  df[(df.ID==id) & (df.YEAR <= year)].VALUE.sum()
print(df)
```

but I'm sure there must be a better and more efficient way of doing it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by `ID` and aggregate with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['CUMULATIVE_VALUE'] = df('ID').VALUE.cumsum()

 ID  YEAR  VALUE  CUMULATIVE_VALUE
0   A  2018    144               144
1   B  2018    147               147
2   C  2018    164               164
3   D  2018    167               167
4   A  2019    167               311
5   B  2019    109               256
6   C  2019    183               347
7   D  2019    121               288
8   A  2020    136               447
9   B  2020    187               443
10  C  2020    170               517
11  D  2020    188               476
```

In the case the years are not sorted instead do:

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','YEAR']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID').agg({'VALUE':'cumsum'})
```

Comment: Although this seemed to work it doesn't if e.g. the years aren't in ascending order - in my example above if you switch the order in the `years` list, e.g. `years=[2019,2018,2020]` then it breaks

Comment: Ok good point. Updated the solution to take this into account

Comment: I did wonder about passing a lambda or a custom function to `agg` instead of having to sort and reset the index of the entire dataframe... but not having any joy so accepting this answer